# Controller model class option is not showing the class name when using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to asp.net mvc so pls bear with me ...
I was following this tutorial [Kudvenkat tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8f4P8U1a2TI&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v&index=25)

and when I am trying to add the Employee class as a model class it is not showing in the model class drop-down list of the model class
[image of drop-down list[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MAQG.png)

pls help

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant details in your actual question (not an offsite link).  We need to know enough information to understand your problem.  What steps have you taken so far?  What have you attempted to try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the model class is **public** and you need to **Rebuild** your project to show it the Models DropDown.

[Understanding Clean, Build and Rebuild in Visual Studio](https://mithunvp.com/clean-build-and-rebuild-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: The problem was Rebuilding and there was this warning  "Running this text template can potentially harm your computer. Do not run it, if u obtained it from an untrusted source..." , I was selecting cancel but had to select Ok that resolved the issue for me